# Artifactory: file not found by Maven if anonymous access is allowed

Tags: maven, artifactory

I have a Maven artifact stored in a protected repository on Artifactory. I have my user credentials set up in the `settings.xml`. At the same time I have configured Artifactory in such a way that it allows anonymous access to some public repositories.

When I now try to download the artifact with Maven, I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get (default-cli) 
  on project artifactory: Couldn't download artifact: Could not find artifact 
  XXX:common:jar:2.2.1-RELEASE in artifactory-XXX (http://XXX/artifactory/XXX)
```

When I disable anonymous access in Artifactory, everything works as expected.

So it seems like Maven is not trying to search for the artifact with the provided user credentials after it can't find it in the public repos of the Artifactory server.

Am I missing some Artifactory configuration or is it not possible to have both public and protected repositories on the same server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you check in the Artifactory UI --> Admin --> Security Configuration --> if the checkbox "Hide Existence of Unauthorized Resources" is checked?

If so this can explain the issue. When this is checked then Artifactory will not show the artifacts for unauthorized users and will return 404. In case this is indeed the issue you can set the [maven to use a preemptive authentication](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html#Example:_Using_Preemptive_Authentication) in order to authenticate from the first request. Here's the snippet that configures preemptive authentication in your `.m2/settings.xml`:

```
<server>
  <id>artifactory</id>
  <configuration>
    <httpConfiguration>
      <all>
        <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
      </all>
    </httpConfiguration>
  </configuration>
  <username>...</username>
  <password>...</password>
</server>
```

If this was not the issue what do you see in the `artifactory.log` and `request.log` in Artifactory after getting this failed message?

Comment: Hi @Ariel, thanks for your answer - that indeed solved my issues. I added a code snippet to your post and linked the Maven documentation.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I've approved the edit. Thank you for that.