# Maven cannot find parent pom from artifactory even though it exists

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I have a simple maven parent-child project. The parent pom sits on it's own project. The project has been tested with a trial artifactory which had maven repo autoconfig. Works smooth there. Unfortunately our corporate artifactory did not have the auto config and the repos were manually created.

Maven deploy on parent works fine. The deploy on child fails in the corporate artifactory since it cannot find the parent. The issue exists on both release and snapshot repos. Maven does search the repo and the file location looks fine(curl to the  location returns the pom and if I put the url in browser, file gets downloaded). Why isn't maven able to download it? It is an auth issue? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Error

[image: mvn clean deploy]

I can simulate the issue with following pom

Parent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.xyzCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>parent-pom</name>
    <description>Parent POM</description>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
        <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>artifactory-snapshots</name>
            <url>https://hidden.jfrog.io/artifactory/busy-libs-snapshot-local</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <name>artifactory-release</name>
            <url>https://hidden.jfrog.io/artifactory/busy-libs-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Child

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.xyzCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-child</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>mule-application</packaging>

    <name>salesforce-data-migration</name>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.xyzCompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
              </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        
</project>
```

Settings

[image]

Nothing much in debug logs either. Please note, busy-libs-release is a virtual repo that reflects the contents of busy-libs-release-local. I am unable to write to the virtual repo. So write to busy-libs-release-local and read from busy-libs-release. Reading directly from busy-libs-release-local also has the same issue.

Comment: according to your configs you are deploying to `busy-libs-release-local` and trying to download from `busy-libs-release`, that seems to be a root cause.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov, Thank you but busy-libs-release is a virtual repo that reflects the contents of busy-libs-release-local. I can't write to busy-libs-release (get a 405). Hence I write to busy-libs-release-local and read from busy-libs-release. I can see the file in the virtual repo and curl but maven cannot find it for some reason. Also, I just tried reading directly from release-local and got the same error - Could not find artifact org.xyzCompany:test-parent:pom:0.0.1 in central (https://hidden.jfrog.io/artifactory/busy-libs-release-local) although the pom's in there.

Comment: Looks like issue was caused by "Hide Existence of Unauthorized Resources" and needs an additional configuration to use preemptive auth. Answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by

[Artifactory: file not found by Maven if anonymous access is allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396013/artifactory-file-not-found-by-maven-if-anonymous-access-is-allowed)

Using pre-emptive authentication seems to have resolved the issue

```
       <server>
          <configuration>
            <httpConfiguration>
              <all>
                <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
              </all>
            </httpConfiguration>
          </configuration>
          <username>{username}</username>
          <password>{password}</password>
          <id>central</id>
        </server>
```